# Why is $^nC_r$ not equal to $ ^{n-k}C_{r-k}\times ^nC_k$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Why is $^nC_r$ not equal to $ ^{n-k}C_{r-k}\times ^nC_k$ ?

I know that by simplifying, we can obviously see that they are unequal. But consider this:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You must take sum of all k goes from 0 to $r$. After that, you must divide by $2^r$,i.e number of all subset of $r$-element set. Finally, you got $${n \choose r} = \frac{1}{2^r}\sum_{k=0}^r {n\choose k}{n-k \choose r-k}$$

Comment: please give a combinatorial insight to the blind soul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you have $n$ white balls, numbered $1$ through $n$. You choose $k$ of them to paint red, and then you choose $r-k$ of the remaining white balls to paint green. Thus, you end up with $k$ red balls, $r-k$ green balls, and $n-r$ white balls.

The number of different outcomes is clearly

$$\binom{n}k\binom{n-k}{r-k}\;:\tag{1}$$

there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose the $k$ balls to paint red, and for each of those there are $\binom{n-k}{r-k}$ ways to choose $r-k$ of the remaining white balls to paint green.

Let $C$ be a set of $r$ of the balls. How many outcomes are there in which $C$ is the set of non-white balls? There are $\binom{r}k$ different $k$-ball subsets of $C$ that could be the $k$ red balls, and of course the other $r-k$ balls will then be the green ones, so there are $\binom{r}k$ such outcomes.

Now imagine that you’re red-green colorblind: those $\binom{r}k$ outcomes will all look the same to you. The $r$ balls in $C$ will appear colored, and the remaining $n-r$ balls will appear white. Thus, you won’t see as many different outcomes as someone who can distinguish the red balls from the green ones (unless, of course, $\binom{r}k=1$, i.e., $k=0$ or $k=r$). How many will you see? One for each possible set $C$ of $r$ colored balls, i.e.,

$$\binom{n}r\;.\tag{2}$$

Thus, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are counting different things, and you should not expect them to be equal.

Comment: oh thank u very much for making it clear!

Comment: do u have any good combinatorics resource in mind for self study?

Comment: @Tim: A lot depends on how much you already know. I like Miklós Bóna, *Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics*, but it might still be a little too advanced. The sections on combinatorics in *Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction*, by Edward A. Scheinerman, are better than average in a classroom setting, but I’m not sure how well they would work for self-study.